# Inverse Laplace of a function

Tags: laplace-transform

I am really searching for hours now for the inverse laplace transformation of the following function:

$$\frac{75s + 12739.726}{s( 0.0365s^2 + 81.2s + 12739.726)}$$

If I put this in WolframAlpha the solution needs to be:

$$1-e^{-2054.79t}-2.11263\times10^{-10}e^{-169.863t}$$

This is a step response of an electrical system.. It is a long time ago I used laplace etc. and some help would be really useful.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not sure what you're asking. Is it A. The answer from WA isn't the one you know otherwise to be correct. How can we resolve that problem?  B. How did WA arrive at that answer step-by-step? C. Something else?

Comment: I am sure the answer of WolframAlpha is correct because I plotted the step response in Matlab and it corresponds to the actual simulation of the system. So I am searching for the step-by-step solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\frac{75s + 12739.726}{s( 0.0365s^2 + 81.2s + 12739.726)} = \frac 1 s   -\frac{ 2.11263 \times 10^{-10}}{s + 169.863} - {1 \over s + 2052.79} $$

Now the inverse Laplace transform of $a \over s + b$ is $ae^{-bt}$ and the inverse Laplace transform of $1/s$ is the identity function (or the Heavyside function).

E.g., $$\mathcal L[ae^{-bt}](s) = a \int_0^\infty e^{-bt}e^{-st} \ dt = \frac{a}{s+b}$$

Does that answer your question?

Comment: I guess you have now used the Laplace transformation of the answer of WolframAlpha? Because I don't know how you have become these three fractions..

Comment: I guess you have used partial fractions here?

Comment: $$\frac{75s + 12739.726}{s(s+169.863)(s+2052.79}$$ 
I understand this because the two values in the denominator are the poles of the system (don't know if you know anything about electrical systems..).
But I don't know how you go from this fraction to the three fractions..

Comment: It's a painful exercise to go from left to right manually, but WA can help you with them as well: 
http://bit.ly/1Bxnw85
Once you have them, it isn't too hard to confirm by hand that the right equals the left. Your algebra above isn't correct.

Comment: Ok, I will check this again. Thank you for your help and effort!

Comment: It's custom on this site if someone has helped you to upvote their answer or to accept it.